# CSS only tooltip

Tags: html, css

I have tried the CSS only tooltip. However, I am not able to add a border to the tooltip's arrow.

Here is my code (see http://jsfiddle.net/1u2kw86m/):

`<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="Automatic resize CSS">Test small Text</a>`

```
.tooltip {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

.tooltip:hover {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.tooltip:after {
    background: #ffffe1;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border:1px solid #DCA;
     box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #ccc;
    bottom: 28px;
    color: #000;
    content: attr(title);
    display: block;
    left: 1em;
    padding:9px 8px 9px 8px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    min-width:200px;
    max-width:500px;
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height:16px;   
}

.tooltip:before {
    border: solid;
    border-color: rgba(255,255,225,1) transparent;
    border-width: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
    bottom: 1em;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;    
}
```

Comment: Next time, please include relevant code in the question, and not just in jsfiddle. There is a reason why this was blocked. Also, you can include runnable snippets, just like jsFiddle in your question itself.

Comment: And of course *"I need a immediate solution."* is never a good argument on a free and voluntary community like this.

Comment: Sorry for that asking immediate solution. forgive me.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to show the `:before` and `:after` only when the elment is hovered.

So

```
.tooltip:after
```

becomes

```
.tooltip:hover:after
```

```css
.tooltip {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}
.tooltip:hover {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tooltip:hover:after {
  background: #ffffe1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #DCA;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #ccc;
  bottom: 28px;
  color: #000;
  content: attr(title);
  display: block;
  left: 1em;
  padding: 9px 8px 9px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 98;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 500px;
  font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 16px;
}
.tooltip:hover:before {
  border: solid;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 225, 1) transparent;
  border-width: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  bottom: 1em;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  left: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<p>Tool tip</p>
<br/>
<br/>

</br><a href="#" class="tooltip" title="Automatic resize CSS">Test small Text</a> 
<br/>
<br/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1u2kw86m/1/

Comment: yes. in that bottom arrow i need a border for that.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't clear to me. You won't be able to do that. One solution would be to add a box-shadow, but that doesn't respect the diagonal border outline. So the only solution would be an extra element or pseudo-element. And since you already used both pseudo-elements, you are going to need an extra element in your html markup. That could, for instance, be an extra span inside our outside the link. In that span, you can create an extra triangle, which has the border color of the outline, and is slightly larger than the yellow arrow you have now.

Answer (score 1):

add a `span` for tooltip so that you can style it better

```css
.tooltip {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}
.tooltip:hover {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tooltip span {
  background: #ffffe1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #DCA;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #ccc;
  bottom: 28px;
  color: #000;
  content: attr(title);
  display: block;
  left: 1em;
  padding: 9px 8px 9px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 98;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 500px;
  font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 16px;
  display: none;
}
.tooltip span:before {
  border: solid;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 225, 1) transparent;
  border-width: 14px 14px 0px 0px;
  bottom: -14px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  left: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.tooltip span:after {
  border: solid;
  border-color: #DCA transparent;
  border-width: 17px 17px 0px 0px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  left: 23px;
  bottom: -17px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
.tooltip:hover span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
hover on a for the tooltip to appear
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br> <a href="#" class="tooltip">Test small Text<span>Automatic resize CSS</span></a>
```